# hyperref with implicit=false gives a warning

Tags: beamer, hyperref, warnings

I am getting the following warning when I use `beamer`

> Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdftitle' has already been used

I can recreate the problem with the following MWE based on the `article` class

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

For reasons that are beyond my understanding (and beyond my desire to know) `beamer` requires `hyperref` to be loaded with `implicit=false`. The `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}}` occurs in a package written by me. Given that I need to load `hyperref` with `implicit=false` and I need to set `pdftitle` after I load `hyperref`, is there a way to avoid this warning (without using the `silence` package)? Yes, I know it is only a warning and doesn't really matter.

Potentially helpful, but also potentially misleading is that

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

doesn't give the warning even though `pdftitle` is given twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more digging and I think I have an answer. The issue is that `implicit` causes `\PDF@FinishDoc` to run earlier than usual. The default behavior of `\PDF@FinishDoc` is to disable the ability of `\hypersetup` to set `pdftitle` and instead cause it to produce a warning. A simple work around is to use `\pdfinfo{/Title (mytitle)}` instead of `\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}`. My guess is that this has some drawbacks, but I don't know what they are yet. Another possibility is to redefine `\PDF@FinishDoc` so it runs later. I am hesitant to make it run later, since my guess is that there is a reason for it to run earlier with `implicit`. It might also be possible to either prevent `pdftitle` from being disabled, or to re-enable `pdftitle`, set it, and then disable it again.

Answer (score 8):

The setting of option `pdftitle` is used in `\PDF@FinishDoc`. Usually it is called at the output of the first page, but with option `implicit` it is done via `\AtBeginDocument`.

Thus, either you can use your call of `\AtBeginDocument` *before* package `hyperref` is loaded, or package `etoolbox` helps with hook `\AtEndPreamble`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{pdftitle=mytitle}}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I wanted to add that with the new `lthooks` it's possible to override `beamer`'s setting 'implicit' to 'OFF':

```
\AddToHook{ package/before/hyperref }
{
    \PassOptionsToPackage{ implicit = true }{ hyperref }
}
```

This will add `implicit=true` to the end of the options passed to `hyperref`. This doesn't cause me any problems for my use of `beamer`, but due to [lack of documentation](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/100) I'm not entirely sure what this *really* does.

Comment: "The implicit option determines whether hyperref redefines LaTeX internals. For beamer, we have a lot of manual redefinitions, so that is not appropriate. This is not documented in the beamer manual as it's essentially a technical aspect for developers: how beamer/hyperref work together." https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/658